# How to load a wfm ( wireframe) in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, opengl-es, 3d

My project is to display a human face in iphone and currently am using opengles and a ".obj" file to load a human model. But for each human face I need to generate different ".obj" file to make the texture mapping accurate.

On googling I got to know about [candide](http://www.icg.isy.liu.se/candide/) which has a wireframe model and also it has the co-ordinates for each facial feature. So it would be good if I get a model like this.

So my question here is, how to export the "wfm" file into ios and get a model? Can some one guide me in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

You could use wmf2svg to convert the wmf to a svg file. See http://code.google.com/p/wmf2svg/
Then you could create objective C code using paintcode. See https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/paintcode/id507897570?mt=12

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But if you look at the co-ordinates of candied it is very less. So Can I do something simple?